# How to reset a form to its default appearance, after interaction with user

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to get default view of my form after some interaction with user. 
In other words after some changes that has been implied by user, what command will return the form to the initial pop up appearance? 
I have many controls, and calculations, so I dont want to go over the control one by one and set them null or their default value.
It would be great, as if I initate the form once more, some how.

Comment: I am assuming the question is for winforms? Retagged...

Answer (score 7):

You could try clearing the controls on the form, then calling the `InitializeComponent()` method.

```
while (Controls.Count > 0)
{
    Controls[0].Dispose();
}
InitializeComponent();
```

**EDIT:**

Another Option that wouldn't cause any performance issues would be to utilize data binding.  Create a data object that maps one to one with all of the fields you'd like to reset, then once it is time to reset the form simply set the data source of your form to a new instance of the data object.

Comment: This leaks window handles badly, it doesn't dispose the controls.

Comment: @Hans Fixed it by disposing the controls.  Obviously disposing the entire form and presenting a new instance would be optimal.

Comment: This still doesn't work, it only disposes the even numbered controls.  Disposing a control also removes it from the Controls collection.  Use: while (Controls.Count > 0) Controls[0].Dispose() and don't call Clear().  Test code before you post it.

Comment: @Hans If disposing a control removes it from the Controls collection, wouldn't an exception be thrown instead of only the even number controls being disposed?

Comment: See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/240692/altering-a-controlcollection-in-a-for-each-loop-doesnt-generate-an-exception

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this too, assuming you just wanted to reset text on the controls. Call the following function with ResetControl(this) where "this" is your form. You'd want to check the control type so you don't have unintended consequences like wiping out label text.

```
private void ResetControl(Control control)
{
  if (control.HasChildren)
    foreach (var ctl in control.Controls)
      ResetControl((Control)ctl);

  if (control is TextBox)
    control.ResetText();
}
```

Although, I still think you'll have far less bugs if you just dispose the form and create a new one (you could load an initial form that loads a user control, and dispose the user control, or use a mdi container form to load another form or something).

Comment: It may be better to set a guard clause of if (control is Label) return;

Comment: I like the user control idea

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write a personalized function `ResetForm()` and reset each component alone :

for TextBox ==>  `TextBox1.Text = "default text";`

for ComboBox ==>  `ComboBox1.ResetText();`

for DataGridView ==> `DataGridView1.RowCount=1;`

etc...